# How can I find the time since an event happened?

Tags: php, datetime, time

The event returns a standardized timestamp in the format of "Sat Oct 25 21:55:29 +0000 2008"
How can I compare this with the current time in PHP so that it gives me the result in a form like "It has been 15 minutes!" or "It has been three days!" Also, how can I get the current time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First convert that string to a UNIX timestamp using [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$event_time = strtotime('Sat Oct 25 21:55:29 +0000 2008');
```

Then to get the current UNIX timestamp use [time()](http://php.net/time):

```
$current_time = time();
```

Then get the number of seconds between those timestamps:

```
$difference = $current_time - $event_time;
```

And finally use division to convert the number of seconds into number of days or hours or whatever:

```
$hours_difference = $difference / 60 / 60;
$days_difference = $difference / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

For more information on calculating relative time, see [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time).

Comment: beat me to it. (ps: gratz on 5000 rep)

Comment: If the input date format is fixed, it may be better to use strptime()